# Odd CSS selector override issue in WebKit / Mozilla browsers (at least)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've run into an odd selector override problem.  I'm trying to override the padding-left for the `.request-desc-download` class in the HTML/CSS below.  Adding in additional classes doesn't seem to help.

**Doctyle**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="letter-list">
    <li>
        <dl class="pers-data">
            <dt>Person:</dt>
            <dd>John Doe</dd>
        </dl>
        <span class="request-desc request-desc-download">
            <a href="#">Download</a>
        </span>
    </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.letter-list .request-desc{
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background: url(../img/icons-request-desc.gif) no-repeat 0 5px;
}
.letter-list > li .request-desc-download{
    background-position:0 -55px;
    padding-left:18x !important;
}
```

**Selectors I've tried:**

```
.letter-list > li .request-desc-download
.letter-list li span.request-desc-download
body .letter-list .request-desc-download
```

None of them fix the padding to the left of the `.request-desc-download` class.  Any thoughts?  The only thing that seems to work is adding the `padding-left` into the `style` attribute of the actual span, which I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written `18x` instead of `18px`!

It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcfah/

```
.letter-list .request-desc{
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.letter-list > li .request-desc-download{
    padding-left: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  Golly, looked at that for 5-10 min <shakes his head in amusement>.  I'll accept your answer in 5 min once I'm allowed to.

Comment: I didn't notice it at first either! Put it in a fiddle, messed around with the selectors and then I saw it. Those darn little things! ;-)